# Between Date function MM/DD/YYYY Mysql

Tags: mysql, date, join, between

I'm trying to get all the records between two dates. However, I'm getting only record with 1 date only. My date structure is Varchar(20).

Here's my query:

Can you help me with this? :(

```
SELECT a.DOB as `DATE`, 
       (CASE when f.INHOUR > 12 or f.INHour = 12 Then 'PM' 
             else 'AM' END) as Shift, 
       concat(b.FIRSTNAME, ' ', b.LASTNAME) Fullname, 
       a.Amount as DECLARED, 
       SUM(c.Amount) as CALCULATED, 
       a.AMOUNT as `NET OF SPECIAL SALES`, 
       d.Amount as `CASH OVER SHORT`, 
       a.AMOUNT as `CASH DEPOSIT` 
FROM   gndsale a 
INNER  JOIN emp b 
ON     a.ID= b.ID 
INNER JOIN gndsale c 
ON     b.ID= c.ID 
INNER JOIN gndsale d 
on     b.ID = d.ID 
INNER JOIN adjtime f 
on    a.ID= f.ID 
WHERE a.type = "22" 
AND   c.type = "4" 
AND   d.type = "42" 
and (a.DOB BETWEEN '5/1/2017' AND '5/19/2017') 
GROUP BY b.ID
```

Comment: _"My date structure is Varchar(20)"_ - that is your mistake you need to fix first. Use one of the date and time types the database provides.

Comment: cant I somehow convert my varchar to date? because all of my data fields are in that format

Comment: When we have `Date`, `Timestamp` data types in MySQL the why you chosen the `varchar` type for the date field values why???

Comment: And the other option is to save the data in `bigint(21)` field and then you can use the `date(format, dateFromDatabase)` to show the date in any format you want and while saving the date in the database just pass the date from the use to the `strtotime(userEnteredDate)` and save the same in the database;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `DOB` column really be text, then you should *seriously* consider switching that column to a date type.  That being said, if you *must* proceed as is, you can leverage MySQL's [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function, which can convert your text dates into actual date types.  Then, use the same `BETWEEN` comparison.  Note also that I replaced your incorrect `mm/DD/YYYY` date literals with ANSI compliant literals of then form `YYYY/mm/DD`.

```
WHERE
    STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB, '%m/%d/%Y') BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-19'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT a.DOB as `DATE`, (CASE when f.INHOUR > 12 or f.INHour = 12 Then 'PM' 
else 'AM' END) as Shift, concat(b.FIRSTNAME, ' ', b.LASTNAME) Fullname, 
a.Amount as DECLARED, SUM(c.Amount) as CALCULATED, a.AMOUNT as `NET OF 
SPECIAL SALES`, d.Amount as `CASH OVER SHORT`, a.AMOUNT as `CASH DEPOSIT` 
FROM gndsale a INNER JOIN emp b ON a.ID= b.ID INNER JOIN gndsale c ON 
b.ID= c.ID INNER JOIN gndsale d on b.ID = d.ID INNER JOIN 
adjtime f on a.ID= f.ID WHERE a.type = "22" AND c.type = "4" 
AND d.type = "42" and (STR_TO_DATE(a.DOB BETWEEN,'%m-%d-%Y') STR_TO_DATE('5/1/2017','%m-%d-%Y') AND '5/19/2017','%m-%d-%Y')) GROUP BY 
b.ID
```

Answer (score 1):

PLEASE TRY:::

```
SELECT a.DOB as `DATE`, 
   (CASE when f.INHOUR > 12 or f.INHour = 12 Then 'PM' 
         else 'AM' END) as Shift, 
   concat(b.FIRSTNAME, ' ', b.LASTNAME) Fullname, 
   a.Amount as DECLARED, 
   SUM(c.Amount) as CALCULATED, 
   a.AMOUNT as `NET OF SPECIAL SALES`, 
   d.Amount as `CASH OVER SHORT`, 
   a.AMOUNT as `CASH DEPOSIT` 
FROM   gndsale a 
INNER  JOIN emp b 
ON     a.ID= b.ID 
INNER JOIN gndsale c 
ON     b.ID= c.ID 
INNER JOIN gndsale d 
on     b.ID = d.ID 
INNER JOIN adjtime f 
on    a.ID= f.ID 
WHERE a.type = "22" 
AND   c.type = "4" 
AND   d.type = "42" 
AND (a.DOB BETWEEN CAST('5/1/2017') as date) AND CAST('5/19/2017' as date) ) 
GROUP BY b.ID
```

THE BETWEEN CLAUSE CANNOT BE USED WITH DATES IN THE FORM OF CHARACTER STRING.
(IT CAN BE, BUT THAT WOULD NOT BE LOGICAL)

CHEERS

Comment: The OP is using MySQL, not SQL Server.

Comment: @VirgilCruz, sorry for that. i have edited the answer. please refer to it.
actually datetime,there, isnt an alias name.

the char date string had to be cast to date datatype. it wouldnt be a problem if its converted to datetime datatype.

Comment: THANKS! :D I got my desired result :)